# Linking StackExchange accounts to Careers CV

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, flair, linked-accounts, cv

Currently only trilogy accounts can be linked and shown on the CV.

Would it be possible for us to add our flair badge from *any* StackExchange site, if you used the same OpenID to register and login?

I can imagine that showing, e.g. your [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) flair, on your CV could be an additional "selling point" for programmers with a strong mathematical orientation.

Answer (score 8):

The StackExchange sites are far too varied in topic to be associated with ***StackOverflow*** Careers.

I can probably speak for Jeff in saying that he would not enjoy being the one to pick and choose which StackExchange sites "qualify" to be linked to StackOverflow Careers.

FWIW, I agree that having a MathOverflow reference on your CV might be advantageous, but I think this is a case where you don't need to change the system to get what you want. Simply add a link to your profile in the appropriate section.

Comment: +1 for adding it to the profile

Comment: I wonder... what *would* be the "appropriate section"?  And why would have it be in another place from the "blessed" sites?  How about *we* can add them ourselves... sort like opt-in instead of the current opt-out (hiding the sites we don't want to show up)?

Comment: @jae: The "Projects and Links" section.